# How to rename artifacts gitlabci?

Tags: android, continuous-integration, gitlab, gitlab-ci

Using this
[GitLab Documentation](http://doc.gitlab.com/ce/ci/yaml/README.html#artifacts)

I created this file .YML

```
    dev:
 script:
       - ./gradlew assembleDebug

 artifacts:
    paths: 
           - app/*.apk
    name:  "myfile"
```

I need rename the result zip to "myfile", but doesn't work properly.

> Console:
>
> BUILD SUCCESSFUL
>
> Total time: 1 mins 33.348 secs 
>   Archiving artifacts...
>   app/*.apk: found
>   1 matching files
>   Creating archive artifacts.zip ...
>   Done!

Answer (score 4, accepted):

**Two** problems which cause malfunction *.yml* file.
The first is the use of **TABS** within the file *.yml*
The second was the versions: **GitLab 8.6** or higher and **GitLab Runner v1.1.0** or higher.

The solution is:

```
dev:
 script:
    - ./gradlew assembleDebug

 artifacts:
  name: "Deploy-Test_${CI_BUILD_REF_NAME}_${CI_BUILD_ID}"    
  paths: 
    - app/*.apk
```